# c_cpp_properties.json file framework error after update

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, c++17, macos-monterey

I was writing code in C++ in VSCode and after I updated the software of my Mac to MacOS 12.5.1, i got an error. This is what my c_cpp_properties.json file looked like.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

After my update, I got this error message:

Cannot find "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks".

Comment: Have you tried looking to see if your sdk got updated and is now in a new location?

Answer (score 0):

Update the path in `"macFrameworkPath"` according to the new content of the directory

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/
```

I would use such the config

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk` always links to the actual MacOS SDK in the directory `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/`.